# Почему возникают ошибки

Tags: java, android

```
1.ошибка в строке 
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

слово this

2.ошибка в строке 
       View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

слово getWindow()
```

package dima113xxx.scr;

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Date;

import static android.R.attr.permission;



public class SCR {

    String folder_main = "Screenshot_Crypto_Calculator";
    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };

    public void check() {



        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }else
        { }

    }

    public void takeScreenshot() {

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folder_main);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.mkdirs();
        }

        Date now = new Date();
        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

        try {
            // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(folder_main) + "/" + now + ".jpg";

            // create bitmap screen capture
            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            File imageFile = new File(mPath);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Several error may come out with file handling or DOM
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь вызывать методы активити не в классе, ею являющейся. Унаследуйте класс от активити или передайте ссылку на неё в ваш класс.